# Running a Shell Script as a Cronjob

Tags: shell, cron, sudo

I have a written a shell script to automate a build process.

The script checksout some code from an SVN repo, compiles and builds the code before extracting the built binary files and storing these in a central location.

I can manually execute the script `./autobuild.sh` and it runs perfectly.  There are a few `sudo` commands executed throughout the script, but I echo the password through for the first sudo command and the password holds for the entire time:

```
echo mypassword! | sudo -S make clean
```

When I add executing the script as a `crontab` it fails to complete all the tasks.  I've tried to add it as a cronjob for the normal and root users.

Running `crontab -e` on my normal user account, I want the script to run at ten past midnight every day:

```
10 0 * * * /home/username/autobuild.sh
```

Also running a 32-but Cent OS 7 install with all the latest updates installed.

Can anyone provide any suggestions as to why it might work manually but not when run through a cron?

Comment: Can you share your crontab line?

Comment: @aadarshsg Good shout, added that and my OS.

Comment: Cron only provides a limited environment and `PATH`. To test if that is the problem, run on the command line: `env -i HOME=$HOME PATH=/usr/bin /home/username/autobuild.sh`. Note that this won't read any of your profile initializations.

Comment: Tried this, it hung on the `mv` command to move the created binary file.

Comment: Hung on `mv`? Any funny file systems there (NFS, automounter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
10 0 * * * /bin/bash /home/username/autobuild.sh
```

Comment: Getting an error `
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` when I try this.  Do I need to echo the password for EACH sudo command?

Comment: I used this mixed with echoing the user's password each time a `sudo` command is called `echo mypassword! | sudo -S make command`.  Not elegant, and NOT recommended for live production systems, but it suits for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. find bash path

```
:~# whereis bash
```

Output

```
bash: /usr/bin/bash
```

step 2. create sh file add the line on top replace with your bash path

#!/usr/bin/bash

step 3. Make the script executable with command chmod +x .

step 4. add cron like this in for every minute to test

crontab -e

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/bash ~/backup.sh >>test.log
```

Comment: Nice explanation!